# Get Values Inside ItemTemplate of ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, itemtemplate

I am trying to get the values coming from an `ItemTemplate`inside my `ListView1` control.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="test message" />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">
    </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</ItemTemplate>

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    int score = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in RadioButtonList1.Items)
        {
            ListViewDataItem theValue = RadioButtonList1.Items[0];
            RadioButtonList myValue = (RadioButtonList)theValue.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");

            score += int.Parse(myValue.SelectedItem.Value);
    }
    // display score
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to get 1,2,3,4 from your radiobuttonlist?  Is that what you are asking, you have a for loop doing that...don't ya ?

Comment: I have 4 records coming from the DataSource. I was thinking of getting the total values collected from the SelectedItem.Value for all items.

Answer (score 2):

Changed the code since it was trying to loop through the items in the RBL, before finding it:

```
  foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType != ListViewItemType.DataItem)
                 continue;

            var rbl = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rbl.SelectedValue))
                 score += int.Parse(rbl.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting a value of O when I used SelectedValue. I tried SelectedItem.Value but receives 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: It's either the selecteditem is null for some reason, or the item is not a data item; I think if you do the following above, it will help too (forget the exact syntax so it may vary).

Comment: @eibhrum SelectedItem may be null if you are binding because you can actually set SelectedValue before items have been bound; it will blow if after binding the value isn't in the list.  So timing wise, it could be performing the action before binding, maybe?